# Min function expressed by max functions

Tags: recurrence-relations, neural-networks

I'm trying to express $\min(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ function in terms of (not nested) ReLU functions relu(x):=max(x,0). The end result should be something like $\min(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\sum_{i_1,\ldots,i_k}c_i\max(g_i(x_{i_1},\ldots,x_{i_k}),0)$, for some function $g$ (e.g., an addition), indices $i_1,\ldots,i_k\in\{1,\ldots, n\}$, and constants $c_i\in\mathbb{R}$.

Let's start:

From basic algebra (I assume henceforth $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$) we know that $|x|=\max(x,0)+\max(-x,0)$ and $x=\max(x,0)-\max(-x,0)$. I join this with $\min(x,y)=\frac 12 (x+y-|x-y|)$ to obtain
$$
\min(x,y)=\frac 12 \left(\max(x+y,0)-\max(-x-y,0)-\max(x-y,0)-\max(-x+y,0)\right).
$$

So far so good. By induction it holds that $\min(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\min(x_1,\min(x_2,\ldots,x_n))$. The problem starts with  $\min(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, as calculations get ugly: $$
\min(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\min(x_1,\min(x_2,x_3))=\frac 12 (\max(x_1+\max(x_2+x_3,0)-\max(-x_2-x_3,0)-\max(x_2-x_3,0)-\max(-x_2+x_3,0),0) - \text{3-other-terms-like-that}.
$$
We can simplify $\max(x_1+\max(x_2+x_3,0))=\max(x_1+x_2+x_3,x_1)$, but it does not help much as in general it is not possibly (imho) to further simplify eq. of type
$$
\max(\max(x_1+x_2+x_3,x_1)-\max(-x_2-x_3,0)-\max(x_2-x_3,0)-\max(-x_2+x_3,0),0)
$$
into not nested max functions, not to mention ReLUs.

I also thought of writing it as a recurrent equation
$$
f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\frac 12 (relu(x_1+f(x_2,\ldots,x_n))-relu(-x_1-f(x_2,\ldots,x_n)) - relu(x_1-f(x_2,\ldots,x_n)) - relu(-x_1+f(x_2,\ldots,x_n)) )
$$
with the initial condition $f(x_1)=x_1$, but so far couldn't figure out anything more from that. Mathematica was not useful either.

I would greatly appreciate any hints.

Thanks!

Comment: Unless I misunderstood that problem it should be quite simple: We know that $\min(x_1,...,x_n)=\min(\min(x_1,...,x_{n-1}),x_n)\,.$ This is a recursion. In other words,
all mins you have to calculate are only between two inputs. Next observe that $\min(x,y)=-\max(-x,-y)=x-\max(x-y,0)$.

Comment: Might be useful : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_transform. Also you can write $\min(x_1,\dots,x_{2k})=\min(\min(x_1,x_2),\dots,\min(x_{2k-1},x_{2k}))$ to do less evaluation of $\min$.

Comment: @KurtG. You said "This is a recursion". I think what you are missing here is that the OP is explicitly asking for a non-nested, in other words non-recursive, solution.

Comment: Nope. You are right, it can be. I had sth else in mind, but it doesn't hold, so never mind. I have deleted the update. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @fdhd I don't think you can do better than have at least $\log_2(n)$ nested-ReLUs as given by Quinton's comment

Comment: @fdhd Is it acceptable to have some products? E.g.  if $x,y,z$ are all different, $\min(x,y,z)=x \frac {\max(y-x,0)\max(z-x,0)}{(y-x)(z-x)}+y\frac{\max(x-y,0)\max(z-y,0)}{(x-y)(z-y)}+z\frac{\max(x-z,0)max(y-z,0)}{(x-z)(y-z)}$.

Comment: @fdhd Perhaps knowing more about the context would help finding solutions. Are you trying to express $\min$ by some neural network, for example?

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni yes, i'm trying to express the min function by a 1-layer ReLU neural network. But as indicated in the comments above, it looks that there needs to be at least $\lceil\log_2 n \rceil +1$ layers ($n$ is the dimensionality)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you meant by no recurrence since when you compute a summation, unless I am mistaken, you are practically using a recurrence especially when dealing with an arbitrary number of elements.

Now if you meant that you can’t use $min(x,y)$ in a recurrence and you are ok using the Relu function. In that case, @kurt gave a simpler use if the maximum function. Here it is broken down:

First we notice that $min(x_1,x_2,x_3,…)=-max(-x_1,-x_2,-x_3,…)$

So to make the answer easier to write, let $y_1=-x_1, y_2=-x_2, y_3=-x_3,…$

Knowing that
$max(y_1,y_2)=y_2+max(y_1-y_2,0)$

We can recursively build the maximum of the $y_i$ by taking
$z_1=y_1$
$z_2=y_2+max(y_2-z_1,0)$
.
.
.
$z_n=y_n+max(y_n-z_{n-1})$

Finally, $min(x_1,x_2,x_3,…)=-z_n$

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I thought it can be done without recursion (non nested), ie as 1-layer ReLU neural network, which is what I hoped for asking the question. I have since realised that it is not possible in the general case, and we need at least the depth of log_2 n. The recursive solution itself is quite straightforward.